# gcc/ld combine libraries which use different versions of the same linked sub-library

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, ld, symbols

I want to compile a program `main` that uses two different modules `m1` and `m2`, each of which uses a different version of the library `./f1/libfa` and `./f2/libf.a.  I *cannot* change the source in the libf libraries, I only have access to main, m1, and m2 sources.

`gfortran -o main main.F90 -L./f1 -lf m1.o -L./f2 -lf m2.o && ./main`

Linker defaults result in `./f1/libf` being used by *both* `m1`and `m2`.  How can I make `m1` use the library from `./f1` and `m2` use the library from `./f2`

Ideas (all of which have failed so far)

- Manipulation link library path (but I can only add to path not remove from path with -L
- use --exclude-libs, hide symbols ...
- Rename symbols during linking stage

A minimal example is available https://github.com/platipodium/multisymbol. Any help greatly appreciated.

I tried `objcopy`

`objcopy --redefine-sym __f_MOD_g=_f1_f_MOD_g f1/libf.a objcopy --redefine-sym __f_MOD_g=_f1_f_MOD_g f1/f.o objcopy --redefine-sym __f_MOD_g=_f1_f_MOD_g m1.o`

Now the symbols seem correct and different, but I get

`gfortran -o main main.F90 -Lf1 -lf m1.o -Lf2 -lf m2.o && ./main m2.o: In function` __m2_MOD_b':
m2.F90:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `__f_MOD_g'`

Directly using the object files now works.

`gfortran -o main main.F90 f1/f.o m1.o f2/f.o m2.o && ./main I am first I am second`

So what's the necessary steps to make it from the above working command with obj files into an archive/library command?

Answer (score 1):

> Linker defaults result in ./f1/libf being used by both m1and m2.

That is expected: that's just [how UNIX linkers work](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

> How can I make m1 use the library from ./f1 and m2 use the library from ./f2

You'll have to rename any conflicting symbols (`objcopy` can do that).

**Update:**

> I tried objcopy ...
>   `gfortran -o main main.F90 -Lf1 -lf m1.o -Lf2 -lf m2.o`

This command line is wrong, for the reasons explained in "how UNIX linkers work" above.

You want:

```
gfortran -o main main.F90 m1.o m2.o -Lf1 -lf -Lf2 -lf
```

Actually, that's not likely to work either: you also want to rename `f2/libf.a` -> `f2/libf2.a` and then:

```
gfortran -o main main.F90 m1.o m2.o -Lf1 -lf -Lf2 -lf2
```

Comment: Yes, it is expected behaviour. I have tried `objcopy` but have not been able to successfully use it.  In both libraries the conflicting symbol is `0000000000000000 T __f_MOD_g`.  Can you add to the minimal example the steps required?

Comment: Thx.  I had to rename `mv f1/libf.a f1/libf1.a` and use your updated command and it works.  Now on to applying this example to a real problem.